# API response code is invalid in powershell script

Tags: powershell, application-pool, powershell-ise

My web application is having a serious issue with app pool. Sometimes, my API application is giving 500 errors and not sending any responses for any request. There are no logical or other runtime errors as I could see and so far I was unable to identify the root cause for that issue. Once I recycle the app pool (app pool is not stopped here), API is working again.

So, until I find the exact root cause for that issue I need to run scheduled powershell script which can recycle the app pool when the API is not responding properly. So, I have created a test endpoint in my API application and my plan is to call that endpoint in every 10mins and check API is working or not.

Even though, the API is giving 400 or 500 errors I get 200 as the response code in my powershell script. Below you can see the ps-1 script and the response is attached here.

```
$HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create('http://api.employeeportal.com/V1/ApiStatus/Test?key=*****')
$error_count = 0;


for ($i=1; $i -le 3; $i++)
{
    $HTTP_Response = $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()
    $HTTP_Status = [int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode

     Write-Host $HTTP_Status
    
    If ($HTTP_Status -eq 200) {           
        break
    }
    Else {
        $error_count++
        Write-Host "Error!"
    }
}

Write-Host $error_count
If($error_count -eq 3){
    Write-Host "App pool downn!!! RESTART--->>>"
}


If ($HTTP_Response -eq $null) { } 
Else { $HTTP_Response.Close() }
```

[image: response]

Why do I get 200 status even though the actual response is 404?  Is there any better way of doing this? Please help!

Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't using ```Invoke-WebRequest```? if you were you could check the status code using ```[int]$error[0].Exception.Response.StatusCode```

Comment: @Otter I tried that command. But it does not execute very next line after execute `Invoke-WebRequest` line. Don't know whether I made any mistake there. I will add here that command line I used `$checkConnection = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://api.employeeportal.com/V1/ApiStatus/Test?key=*****'`

Comment: You can use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to view detailed error information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have figured out a way to do this. Thanks to @Otter I tried the same method again with -ErrorVariable variable and it worked. If someone is looking for an answer to a same kind of problem here is my answer.

In the solution, I'm sending 3 requests to make sure the server is responding or not. If all 3 requests get server errors then I need to restart the app-pool. Also I'm logging the server errors I get for further reference. So this will be a complete answer (I guess so :) )

```
$Logfile = "C:/Errors/log.log"
$error_count = 0;
$error_message = "";

function LogWrite
{
    Param([string]$logstring)
    Add-content $logfile -value $logstring
}

for ($i=1; $i -le 3; $i++)
{
    Invoke-RestMethod http://api.employeeportal.com/V1/ApiStatus/Test?key=***** -ErrorVariable myerror
    $statusCode = [int]$myerror.ErrorRecord.Exception.Response.StatusCode
 
    If($statusCode -ge 500){
        $error_count++  
        $error_message = $myerror.ErrorRecord.Exception.ToString() 
    }
    else{
        break
    }
}

If($error_count -eq 3){
    Restart-WebAppPool -Name "name of your app-pool"
    LogWrite "====== APP-POOL RESTARTED..!!! ======="
    LogWrite $(Get-Date)
    LogWrite $error_message
    LogWrite "=============================================="
}
```